# Finding equivalent to % for the inner if clauses

Tags: c#

I have a static list of descriptions in a resource and I am filtering down the list based on the index positions of the text in the array

Here is my multi converter:

```
using OCLMEditor.Data.StudentInfo.Enums;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace OCLMEditor.ValueConverters
{
    public class StudentAssignmentTypeFilterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            StudentAssignmentType[] allTypes = values[0] as StudentAssignmentType[];
            List<StudentAssignmentType> filteredTypes = new List<StudentAssignmentType>();
            int iNumberOfClasses = values[1] != null ? (int)values[1] : 0;

            if (iNumberOfClasses == 3) // Main hall, Class 1 and Class 2
                return allTypes;

            if(iNumberOfClasses == 0)
            {
                // What to return? It should not get here as the combo is disabled if 
                return allTypes;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < allTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                if(iNumberOfClasses >= 1)
                {
                    if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 12 || i == 15 || i == 18)
                        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
                }

                if(iNumberOfClasses >= 2)
                {
                    if (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7 || i == 10 || i == 13 || i == 16 || i == 19)
                        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
                }

                if (iNumberOfClasses == 3)
                {
                    if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8 || i == 11 || i == 14 || i == 17 || i == 20)
                        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
                }
            }

            return filteredTypes;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think the if clauses inside can be simplified somehow?

Specifcally these three if clauses. Eg:

```
if(iNumberOfClasses >= 1)
{
    if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9 || i == 12 || i == 15 || i == 18)
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
}
```

I know about using `%` to get the (modulus(?)) remainder of a division. So if my numbers were 1, 5, 10, 15, 20 I could use `number % 5 == 0` to get all of them. But ican't see that I can do that here?

Comment: How about a better title and a few more details about what the code does etc.? :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t Indeed. But I don't really know how to re-phrase the title.

Comment: Well, it's not that hard... you know what it does... make it short and put it in the title...

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. There is a condition that reads `if (iNumberOfClasses == 3) return allTypes;` but the same condition you have later inside the loop... you may remove it there. It will never be reached.

Comment: @t3chb0t Good catch! I don't even need that clause in there. :)

Comment: The answer to your "sub question" is: if(i < 21 && i % 5 == 0) but it's much more readable if you create a list of values if this is not a math problem.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you the *modulus* way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer of **t3chb0t**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/133920/22020) provides a solution in the right direction. My point of "critique" with that solution is the overdose on LinQ for a simple solution like checking if a collection of numbers contains a certain number.

The point of predefining the collection is a good idea. I would do it like this:

```
var classesForOne = new [] { 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18 };
var classesForTwo = new [] { 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19 };
var classesForThree = new [] { 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20 };
```

Now you can check if the variable `i` is present in a collection. This can be done like this:

```
if(iNumberOfClasses >= 1)
{
    if (classesForOne.Contains(i))
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
}
```

Writing it this way, you can combine the two `if` statements in one simpler statement:

```
if(iNumberOfClasses >= 1 && classesForOne.Contains(i))
{
    filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
}
```

So the whole code with loop would now look like following:

```
var classesForOne = new [] { 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18 };
var classesForTwo = new [] { 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19 };
var classesForThree = new [] { 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20 };

for(int i = 0; i < allTypes.Length; i++)
{
    if(iNumberOfClasses >= 1 && classesForOne.Contains(i))
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);

    if(iNumberOfClasses >= 2 && classesForTwo.Contains(i))
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);

    if(iNumberOfClasses == 3 && classesForThree.Contains(i))
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
}
```

**Edit:**

### The *mod* implementation:

This edit is not mandatory, it is just provided as extra information to your secondary question about using the modulus. You CAN implement the modulus-way to achieve the same result. I'm not saying this is a *better* implementation, just showing how it can be done :) . Let's look at each of the three cases.

- { 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18 }

If `i` is divisible by 3, meaning it has a remainder of 0, it is in the first collection of numbers.

- { 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19 }

If `i` is divided by 3, remainder 1, it is in the second collection.

- { 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20 }

And for the last, if `i` is divided by 3, remainder 2, it is in the third.

Of course using this method you're not validating if the number `i` is valid within the range. If for example `i` is 22 (remainder is 1), the result would say that it is present in the second collection. You'll have to build in an extra check for this. Here's the implementation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < allTypes.Length; i++)
{
    if(iNumberOfClasses >= 1 && (i <= 18 && i % 3 == 0))
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);

    if(iNumberOfClasses >= 2 && (i <= 19 && i % 3 == 1))
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);

    if(iNumberOfClasses == 3 && (i <= 20 && i % 3 == 2))
        filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
}
```

In this way, you don't need to predefine a collection, the counterpart is that you have to built an extra check to set the maximum allowed number. Hope this explains it. :)

Comment: Thank you for the extra clarification about `Mod`.

Comment: I prefer the _arrays_ autogenerated. Should you want to add another item you need to update three of them. With automation you just change a single number ;-] even better that they can be created with the `mod`.

Comment: @t3chb0t Auto-creation certainly has its advantages as you point out, but if the collections never change, it would be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest I can think of is to generate the numbers first and then make the conditions shorter by checking if the `i` is in the particular collection:

```
var classesFromZero = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5)
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 1), (arr, next) => arr.Concat(new[] { arr.Last() + 3 }))

var classesFromOne = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5)
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Repeat(1, 1), (arr, next) => arr.Concat(new[] { arr.Last() + 3 }))

var classesFromTwo = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 5)
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Repeat(2, 1), (arr, next) => arr.Concat(new[] { arr.Last() + 3 }))

for (int i = 0; i < allTypes.Length; i++)
{
    if (iNumberOfClasses >= 1 && classesFromZero.Contains(i)) filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
    if (iNumberOfClasses >= 2 && classesFromOne.Contains(i)) filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
    if (iNumberOfClasses == 3 && classesFromTwo.Contains(i)) filteredTypes.Add(allTypes[i]);
}
```

This is just a sample. I'd be good to define the magic numbers as constants.

Comment: I cannot comment on the logic because you didn't tell us what the code exacly does any why does it do what it does ;-]

Comment: I have a static list of descriptions in a resource and I am filtering down the list based on the index positions of the text in the array.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Please add this info to the question body.